# React hook form: How to can I use onChange on React Hook Form Version 7.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

Previously I used to write like this:

```html
<input className="form-control" name="productImage" type='file' onChange={handleImageUpload} ref={register({ required: true })} />
```

After the update I have to write like this:

```html
<input className="form-control" type="file" {...register('productImage', { required: true })} />
```

How do I use `onChange={handleImageUpload}` on the updated version of React Hook Form?
Here is the migration [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7/)

Please pardon my mistakes in the manner of asking the question. I'm new to these things.
Thank you.

Comment: You don't have to make any changes to the `onChange` prop in react-hook-form v7.0.0.

Comment: How can I call handleImageUpload() by using onChange={handleImageUpload) like the first line of code I have shown?

Comment: `onChange={handleImageUpload)` should work. Can you share a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) if you're running into any issues?

Comment: Here's my [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-silence-78tcg?file=/src/App.js) and the onChange={handleImageUpload} doesn't work in my code.

Comment: The `handleImageUpload` function does get called when you upload a file.

Comment: I just uninstalled the version 7.0 and installed 6.13.1. On the older version, it works for me just fine but for version 7.0 it didn't work. I really don't know what went wrong. But Thank You for helping me out. Truly appreciate your concern.

Comment: I've been dealing with this issue, you can call register and store the object to a variable, and then manually set those values. It sucks but it works.

Comment: For those new to this thread, the problem with just adding `onChange` is that in RHF v7.x calling `...register('name')` spreads an object containing `{onChange, onBlur, name, ref}`, so the custom handler will either be ignored or override RHF functionality. See @Bill's answer for the proper way to deal with this.

Answer (score 109):

https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/releases/tag/v7.16.0

V7.16.0 has introduced this new API for custom `onChange`.

```
<input
  type="text"
  {...register('test', {
    onChange: (e) => {},
    onBlur: (e) => {},
  })}
/>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer given @Joris's solution would override the change handler spread from `{...register('name')}` which returns `{onChange, onBlur, name, ref}`, and this could lead to bugs.

Comment: @Bill, is it possible to achieve the same with the Controller component?

Comment: yes @Kort with the controlled component you can intercept the onChange prop.

Comment: onChange: (e) => {console.log(e.target.value)} worked for me !

Comment: My time saver! Thanks!

Comment: What if we want to use the native `onChange` but also have it do something else?

Answer (score 46):

You just have to move the `onChange` props after `{...register(...)}`

```
const productImageField = register("productImage", { required: true });

return (
    <input
        className="form-control"
        type="file"
        {...productImageField}
        onChange={(e) => {
          productImageField.onChange(e);
          handleImageUpload(e);
     }}
    />
)
```

**(Dec 3 2021) edit:** this approach is no longer correct since [react-hook-form v7.16.0's changes](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/releases/tag/v7.16.0), see @Bill's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69448858/541961).

Comment: @DiamondDrake are you sure this overrides the onChange function? The example above overrides first the onChange function but then invokes it within our overriden onChange function `productImageField.onChange(e);`. So, what is it that i don't get here?

Comment: @Tanckom I've updated my reply since @ DiamondDrake commented

Comment: @Joris, might be good to mention this in your answer as new viewers may get confused that this is not the correct way :-)

Comment: @Tanckmon is correct, this solution would override the `onChange` handler spread from `{...register('name')}` and could lead to bugs. @Bill's answer seems to be the right one here.

Answer (score 7):

In `register` documentation https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register, sample  exists on `Custom onChange, onBlur` section :

```
// onChange got overwrite by register method
<input onChange={handleChange} {...register('test')} />

// register's onChange got overwrite by register method
<input {...register('test')} onChange={handleChange}/>

const firstName = register('firstName', { required: true })
<input 
  onChange={(e) => {
    firstName.onChange(e); // method from hook form register
    handleChange(e); // your method
  }}
  onBlur={firstName.onBlur}
  ref={firstName.ref} 
/>
```

So for your case :

```
const productImageRegister = register("productImage", {required: true})
<input className="form-control"
       type="file"
       {...productImageRegister }
       onChange={e => {
           productImageRegister.onChange(e);
           handleImageUpload(e);
       }} />
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [react-hook-form control](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/control)

```
  <Controller
  render={({ field }) => <input onChange={event=>{
      handleImageUpload(event);
      field.onChange(event);
    }} />}
  name="image"
  control={control}
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Was stuck with the same problem. For me the problem was that my **onChange** was above the react-hook-form's **{...register}** and moving it below the register solved the problem for me!!

Comment: not a solution, this prevents you from typing in the form field

Answer (score 1):

For me, decoration solution worked

```
const fieldRegister = register("productImage", {required: true})
const origOnChange = fieldRegister.onChange
fieldRegister.onChange = (e) => {
    const res = origOnChange(e)
    const value = e.target.value
    // do something with value
    return res
}
```

For field declaration use

```
<input {...fieldRegister}/>
```

Comment: A little verbose, but this works great for those running on anything earlier than [v7.16.0](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/releases/tag/v7.16.0)

Answer (score 1):

I am using form hook's watch method to capture changes instead of the input's onChange event.

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue recently when migrating to V7. If it can help anybody.

A parent component handling the form was passing down to a wrapper the register function, the wrapper passing it down again to an input that needed debouncing on change.

I called the register `formLibraryRef` in case I wanted to use a different library later but overall I had to do something like:

`const { onChange, ...rest } = formLibraryRef(inputName);`

pass the onChange to the function that is itself passed to the native onChange event of the input:

```
const handleDebouncedChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void = (
    event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
  ) => {
    onChange(event);
    if (preCallback) {
      preCallback();
    }
    debounceInput(event);
  };
```

and then pass the rest to the input:

```
<input
  aria-label={inputName}
  name={inputName}
  data-testid={dataTestId}
  className={`form-control ...${classNames}`}
  id={inputId}
  onChange={handleDebouncedChange}
  onFocus={onFocus}
  placeholder={I18n.t(placeholder)}
  {...rest}
/>
```

The `register` section in the docs here: https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7/ gives a bit more info on how to get the onChange and shows an example for `Missing ref`.

Answer (score 0):

When using a `Controller` with a `control` instance I created a `handleOnChange` method that essentially extends the `onChange` method passed by the `Control.render` method.

Like so:

```js
const SomeForm = () => {
  const { control, getValues } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { foo: 1, bar: 2 },
    mode: "all",
    reValidateMode: "onChange",
    shouldUnregister: false,
  });

  const onChangeHandler = useCallback((onChange: (...event: any[]) => void) => {
    return (...event: any[]) => {
      onChange(...event);

      const formAfterChange = getValues();
      // do what you want after the change happens.
    };
  }, [getValues]);


  return <>
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={"foo"}
      render={({ value, onChange }) => (
        <Input
          value={value}
          onChange={onChangeHandler(onChange)}
        />
      )}
    />

    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={"bar"}
      render={({ value, onChange }) => (
        <Input
          value={value}
          // if you do some logic before calling onChange
          onChange={(e) => {
            let nextValue;
            if ((e.target.value ?? 0) >= 100) {
              nextValue = e.target.value + 10;
            } else {
              nextValue = e.target.value;
            }
            onChangeHandler(onChange)(nextValue);
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  </>;
}
```