# TypeScript, 'onChange' is specified more than once, so this usage will be

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using material-ui, react-hook-form and Typescript in a react project, and when I try to add onChange in TextField VScode show me and error:

> 'onChange' is specified more than once, so this usage will be
> overwritten.ts(2783) formComponent.tsx(33, 15): This
> spread always overwrites this property.

**formComponent.tsx** :

```
        <TextField
          variant="standard"
          defaultValue={projectData.name}
          onChange={handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}
          {...register('name', { required: true })}
          error={!!errors.name}
        />
```

Comment: Presumably `onChange` is one of the props returned by the `register` function. TypeScript is telling you that the one returned by `register` is going to overwrite the `onChange` that you included explicitly. If you want the explicit one to win, it needs to be after the spread of the `register` props.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You have to put onChange after the register spread

```
const textField = register('name', { required: true })

return (
    <input
        className="form-control"
        type="file"
        {...textField}
        onChange={(e) => {
          textField.onChange(e);
          handleSubmit(e);
     }}
    />
)
```

[React hook form: How to can I use onChange on React Hook Form Version 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66936135/react-hook-form-how-to-can-i-use-onchange-on-react-hook-form-version-7-0)