# On click on the `submit` button in the form system is not getting the form field values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On click on the `submit` button in the form is not getting the form field values. Can someone please advise what could be the issue here ?
Following are the versions I am using in the project :
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"express": "^4.18.1",
"multer": "^1.4.4",
"mysql2": "^2.3.3",
"react-hook-form": "^7.31.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
"react-tweet-embed": "^2.0.0"

//Codesandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-currying-5gng14?file=/src/App.js

//proxy settings:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
```

// requestToJoin.js

```
     const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }} = useForm();
        const [loginData, setLoginData] = useState("");
        const [helperText, setHelperText] = useState('');
        const [isSent, setIsSent] = useState(false);
        const [formRegister, setRegister] = useState({ _id: '', name: '', email: '', mobile: '', photo: '', code: ''});
    
           const onChange = (e) => {
                e.persist();
                setRegister({ ...formRegister, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
              }
    
     const onSubmit = e => {
                const formData = new FormData();
              
                for(let key in formRegister) {
                  formData.append(key,formRegister[key]);
                }
              
                if (picture) formData.append("photo", picture);
              
                const config = {
                  headers: {
                      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' 
                  }
                }
                  const fetchData = async () => {
                    try {
                      const res = await axios.put('http://localhost:8000/service/joinrequest', formData, config);
                      console.log("Front End success message:" + res.data.success);
                      if (res.data.success) {
                        setIsSent(true);

                  }
                  else {
                    console.log(res.data.message);
                    setHelperText(res.data.message);
                  }
                } catch (e) {
                  setHelperText(e.response.data.message);
                }
              }
              fetchData();
            }

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}  className="myForm" encType="multipart/form-data">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input
                            id="name"
                            name="name"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={onChange}
                            {...register("name", { 
                                required: true,
                                maxLength: 30
                            })}
                        />
                        <section>
                        <span className="nameValidationText">
                             {errors.name && errors.name.type === "required" && <span>Name is required !</span>}
                             {errors.name && errors.name.type === "maxLength" && <span>Name should be less than 30 characters !</span>}
                             
                         </span>
                        </section>
                
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input
                            id="email"
                            name="email"
                            type="email"
                            onChange={onChange}
                            {...register("email", { 
                                required: true,
                                pattern: {
                                    value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
                                    message: "Please enter a valid email !"
                                }
                            })}
                        />
                        <section>
                        <span className="emailValidationText">
                             {errors.email && errors.email.type === "required" && <span>Email is required !</span>}
                             {errors.email && <span>{errors.email.message}</span>}
                         </span>
                        </section>
                        <label>Mobile</label>
                        <input
                            id="mobile"
                            name="mobile"
                            type="number"
                            onChange={onChange}
                            {...register("mobile", { 
                                required: true,
                                valueAsNumber: true,
                                maxLength: 10
                            })}
                        />
                        <section>
                        <span className="nameValidationText">
                             {errors.mobile && errors.mobile.type === "required" && <span>Mobile is required !</span>}
                             {errors.mobile && errors.mobile.type === "maxLength" && <span>Maximum of 10 digits</span>}
                         </span>
                        </section>

                        <label>Code</label>
                        <input
                            id="code"
                            name="code"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={onChange}
                            {...register("code", { 
                                required: true,
                                maxLength: 6,
                                pattern: {
                                    value:/^[0-9a-zA-Z(\-)]$/, // /^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/i, ///^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/i
                                    message: "Only alphanumeric characters allowed !"
                                  }
                            })}
                        />
                        <section>
                        <span className="nameValidationText">
                             {errors.code && errors.code.type === "required" && <span>Code is required !</span>}
                             {errors.code && <span>{errors.code.message}</span>}
                             
                         </span>
                        </section>

                         <label>
                            <span className="loginValidationText">{helperText}</span>
                         </label>
                        <section className="col-low">
                        <input type="submit" />
                        </section>  
                    </form>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show what the contents of `formData` is prior to you performing the axios request. What shows up in the developer network tools as the body of the API request?

Comment: It is not getting the values from the field, while setting the break point, it is not going further after onSubmit.

Comment: Screenshot attached

Comment: I could see the form data is displaying as null values

Answer (score 0):

You just have to move the onChange props after {...register(...)}

I.e.

```
                    <input
                        id="name"
                        name="name"
                        type="text"
                        {...register("name", { 
                            required: true,
                            maxLength: 30
                        })}
                        onChange={onChange}
                    />
```

Note. This solution will not work past react-hook-form Version 7.16.0 due to the [introduction of an onChange API inside the register function](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/releases/tag/v7.16.0)

```
<input
  type="text"
  {...register('test', {
    onChange: (e) => {},
    onBlur: (e) => {},
  })}
/>
```

See Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69448858/5705891)

Comment: Thank you, when I changed the onChange to after register it is geting the feld values, but as you suggested onChange API it is not working any more