# HTML form is submitted up-to-date when I press Enter instead of clicking button

Tags: reactjs

I have `form` like below.

```
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onValid)}>
            <input
                {...register("searchname", { required: "이름을 적어주세요." })}
                onChange={(text)=> setSearchinput(text)}
                type="text" placeholder="이름을 검색해주세요." className="focus:outline-none focus:border-[#FF2D78] border-2 w-56 border-gray-500 rounded-md py-1 text-center"></input>
            <button className="bg-gray-300 rounded-md py-1 px-3 ml-2">검색</button>
        </form>
```

and I use `useForm()` to submit this form.

It works perfect.

But when I press `enter` instead of clicking `button`.

input value is not up-to-date or isn't applied at all.

for example,

I wrote input as 'abc' and then 'cdb' and press enter then abc value is applied, not cdb.

How to submit with up-to-date input with enter key instead of clicking?

Comment: please add the tag `react` to your question, that's JSX, not HTML

Comment: if you use question tags as javascript and htrml, please provide an example with no further syntax (react) like `{...register("sear...` so it will be easier to perfectly catch your scenario. Talking in general terms, when you submit a form, both by pressing the actual submit button or pressing enter when that button (or the whole form maybe) has focus, should submit the form with the values the input have in that moment. Your description is hard to believe

Comment: I change the tag sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed something similar to that when using the register together with the onChange prop direct on the input. I just tried it on my repo and I got your issue if I add onChange to the input:

https://github.com/joaoeffting/multi-step-form-with-react-hook-forms/blob/main/src/components/StepOne.tsx#L38

I've found this here on the site and it worked:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69448858/5288271

Basically, do this (move the onChange inside the register):

```
{...register("searchname", { required: "이름을 적어주세요.", onChange={(text)=> setSearchinput(text)} })}
```